# Qfield: OSM data not displayed, layer is grey

Tags: openstreetmap, qfield

I am using QGIS 2.18.20 and Qfield 0.10.13 Kesch on Android 7.0.
In order to transfer data to the Android device, I am storing the project file and all related files in a specific folder which I copy with a sync program to the device.

In another post, it was mentioned that the x-y-z tile server is compatible with Qfield. However, all I am getting on the device, is the OSM layer with a grey background, even though it is set to visible plus a blank image of the layer.

I have tried to save the layer in QGIS as a tiff file, but I am getting the message that this format is not supported.

How do I get OSM raster data onto my device?